# SSIS: Dynamic Lookup Query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl, ssis-2016

I would like to implement the following logic to my Lookup query as an expression:

```
SELECT  ID,
        CASE @[User::ConnectionStringID]
        WHEN 1 THEN "NE"
        WHEN 2 THEN "BALT"
        WHEN 3 THEN "NY" 
        WHEN 4 THEN "PA"
        END AS Region
FROM    dbo.Table;
```

My package is executed in a loop where the connection string is dynamically updated using a config file and it loops 4 times as shown in the above logic.

I realized today that the Lookup transformation has no expressions available to it and I haven't been able to find another suitable solution. Has anyone found a way around this or a custom transformation script?

Comment: If you access `@@servername` property or something similar with `SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') As ServerName` can't you change up your conditional?

Comment: If SSIS already has the necessary info to build the column without the Lookup, then use a Derived Column or other transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lookup control has expressions, but cannot accessed directly from it just go to your `Dataflowtask` properties and access the expressions like shown in the image below

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response. I see those two fields in the properties view but how did you open this expressions editor for the Data Flow Task?

Comment: Click on the dataflowtask and press F4 to get the properties tab like shown on the right side of the image. In the properties tab click on the expressions

Comment: When clicked on expressions property a little button will appear on it. Click it to open this window