# Azure Blob Destination in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-blob-storage, etl, sql-server-data-tools

How do you pass blob name as variable in `Azure Blob Destination` in SSIS just like passing tablename as variable in `OLEDB destination`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the control flow tab, click on the `DataFlow Task`, containing the `Azure blob destination` press `F4` key to show the properties tab. Click on the expressions. You will find all `Azure blob destination` that can be passed as a variable.

Look at my answer in the following link it is a similar issue

[SSIS: Dynamic Lookup Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42032542/ssis-dynamic-lookup-query)

Comment: Additionally, the provided parameters need to be in lowercase, otherwise the component will raise an (cryptical) error.